# DeltaSpike @Scheduled does not firing

Tags: quartz-scheduler, deltaspike

My job annotated with @Scheduled does not fire the task. 
I am using Wildfly 10

deltaspike-scheduler-module 1.5.3

quartz 2.2.2

Quartz alone works fine.

My actual code problem:

```
@Scheduled(cronExpression = "0 * * * * ?")
public class CronTask implements Job{

static public final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CronTask.class.getName());

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    log.info("Run");
    System.out.println("aaaaa");


  }

}
```

Any help is welcome.

PS: This code on Jboss EAP works

Comment: I tried your code in WildFly 10 and it worked. You can poke the project that I used here: <https://github.com/rafabene/demo_deltaspike/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rafabene/demos/deltaspike/domain/services/CronTask.java>

Answer (score 0):

I will use EJB Timer 3.2.

tutorial below:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/creating-clustered-ejb-3-timers

Answer (score 0):

I made it work that way, I use Deltaspike. Try another cron expression, like 0 0/1 * * * ? that should trigger it once per minute

Answer (score 0):

i hat to make it @ApplicationScoped to get picked up!

```
    @AppplicationScoped
    @Scheduled(cronExpression = "0 * * * * ?")
    public class CronTask implements Job{

    static public final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CronTask.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        log.info("Run");
        System.out.println("aaaaa");
      }
    }
```

Wildfly 16, Deltaspike Version 1.9.1